# One page selection in DataTable PrimeVue

Tags: vue.js, multipleselection, primevue

**I use DataTable with a paginator. I have a Column with multiple selection mode. I want this column to select only one page rows instead of all table data. Is it possible in PrimeVue?**

I have over 10k rows in a table and this number will always change, therefore I can't use a lazy datatable. I need to select all rows but it's not possible with such a large amount of data, instead I need to select just one page view, just like in Gmail when selecting the e-mails.